# Как передать контекст при вызове функции через onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Необходимо, чтобы при клике на "DOM-элемент" блок `<p>Hello!</p>` внутри него менялся на `<p>Goodbye!</p>`. Для этого был написан следующий реакт компонент:

```
import React from 'react'

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div
                onClick={() => {this.innerHTML = '<p>Goodbye!</p>'}}
            >
                    <p>Hello!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

То есть по сути я хочу добиться следующего, но в React.

```html
<div>
    <div
        onclick="this.innerHTML = '<p>Goodbye!</p>'"
    >
            <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Однако в реакт событие onClick работает несколько иначе и принимает this за undefined, как тогда передать контекст?

Comment: В этом случае, никак. Используйте event.target, чтобы заменить innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прям втупую, то так:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => (
    <p onClick={e => e.target.innerHTML = 'Goodbye'}>Hello</p>
)


export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше используйте состояние компонента.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [markUp, setMarkUp] = useState("<p>Hello!</p>");
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markUp }}
        onClick={() => setMarkUp("<p>Goodbye!</p>")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: здесь лучше условный вывод использовать, потому что вставляемы html в общем случае может отличаться и одной текстовой переменной будет уже не обойтись

Comment: @Grundy, я бы так сделал даже. Беря в учет, что там можно использовать хтмл разметку

Comment: как вариант :) но как-то не безопасно, если не знаешь откуда html приходит

Comment: @Grundy, это да. Но тут показал принцип, что так можно